# FFMPEG Concat protocol does not combine video files

Tags: ffmpeg

So I've tried using the following command to combine 2 video files with the same codec:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:/home/mike/downloads/a1.mp4|/home/mike/downloads/a2.mp4" -c copy "/home/mike/downloads/output.mp4"
```

The the result: `output.mp4` only contains video from `a1.mp4`. I also tried 2 or more file but the result is the same. What could be the possible cause for this? Please help

Mike

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot concatenate `mp4` files directly with the `concat protocol` because the format doesn't support it. This is intended for `mpg` or `mpeg-ts` and similar.

You can do it if you pass by one of those formats:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

The alternative is to use the `concat demuxer` which is more flexible (you still need the same codecs for the input files but it can use different containers):

`ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output`

Where `mylist.txt` is something like:

```
# this is a comment
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

[Documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.